# MySql constraints don't work on mysql Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, check-constraints

I've installed mysql in my ubuntu  using the classic command:

```
     apt-get install mysql-server
```

And to my surprise it is a mysql which doesnt respect any constraint i write with "check".
Could you tell me is it a bug or I don't know how to use constraints in mysql? (i mostly wrote commands in sql simple)

For example these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
Name    VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
Phone VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'Unknown Phone',
Age     INT CHECK (Age BETWEEN 20 and 30));

INSERT INTO Employee (Name, PhoneNo, Age) VALUES ('Joe Wang', '666 2323', 26);
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age) VALUES ('John Doe', 31);
```

And now the table looks like this:

```
| Name     | PhoneNo       | Age  |
| Joe Wang | 666 2323      |   26 |
| John Doe | Unknown Phone |   31 |

2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

How can it be possible?

Comment: It allows `CHECK` in the table definition but it won't use it to enforce data integrity, it silently ignores what you specified in `CHECK`.

Comment: what can i use instead of it?

Comment: Trigger in combination with stored procedure or validate the data before sending it to MySQL. You can create table called `ages` and set FK constraints. There are many ways, it all depends on what you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but....

> > > The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Comment: so sad, how can i replace CHECK with something of real effect?

Comment: With a trigger! Here's an example: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?136,432351,432777#msg-432777